# CMake + Cuda: compile cpp files in Cuda-mode (--x=cu)

Tags: c++, cuda, cmake

Suppose I have a file, let's call it `foo.cpp`, my goal is to compile this file with nvcc in **cuda** mode. From the command-line this can be easily accomplished by invoking:

`nvcc --x=cu foo.cpp`

What I'm struggling with, is to get CMake to do this exact same thing. It turns out that the CMake command `cuda_add_executable(foo foo.cpp)` will filter the *.cpp files and use the c++-compiler (instead of nvcc).

Note that renaming all the files to *.cu is not an option as the codebase has to also support non-cuda builds.

Comment: Can you try to set CMAKE g++ compiler and set its flag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [FindCUDA source code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.3.0/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake#L1305) I found an option to activate CUDA compilation for specific non-`.cu` files. Though it seems documentation is lacking (outside of the source code).

You can set CUDA compilation on a per file level with

```
set_source_files_properties( foo.cpp PROPERTIES CUDA_SOURCE_PROPERTY_FORMAT OBJ )
```

in **CMAKE 3.3** or later.

The rest works as usual:

```
cuda_add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
```

---

Actually, I expected there should be an easy solution like using `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` or `cuda_add_executable( ... OPTIONS --x=cu )` to pass the `--x=cu` flag in. Unfortunately, it does not work. The reason is probably that the scope for a  setting at that level would not be useful, since it would affect all files.